# Bash: how to check if any subshell failed?

Tags: bash, parallelism, subshell

Consider this code:

```
job()
{
  local id=$1
  sleep $id
}
do_job_in_parallel()
{
  local pids=()

  # run subshells
  for id in $(seq 4)
  do
    job $id &
    pids=("${pids[@]}" $!)
  done

  # wait subshells
  for ((i=0; i<${#pids[@]}; ++i))
  do
    local pid=${pids[$i]}
    wait $pid
    exit_status=$?
    if [[ $exit_status -ne 0 ]]
    then
      echo "job with pid $pid failed with exit status $exit_status"
      #TODO: kill all subshells
    fi
  done
}
```

Consider that we need to implement "if any subshell failed, then all subshells failed" logic. If waiting of X and Y is done sequentially (as in the code above) AND if, for example, Y failed while waiting of X, then there is no need to wait X. How to implement, more precisely, "if any subshell failed, then kill immediately all other subshells"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy solution with a for loop and `wait` but you can use GNU parallel (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for this. It should be available for your distribution in your favorite package manager.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

do_job()
{
  local id=$1
  sleep $id
}


export -f do_job

do_job_in_parallel()
{
    parallel --halt now,done=1 do_job "{}" ::: $(seq 4)
}

do_job_in_parallel
```

Besides "now,done=1" you have other options: `soon` instead of `now` only stops starting new jobs but let ongoing processes exit normally, `success=1` stops them only if the process exited with 0, `fail=1` only if if exited with something else, you can specify a number or a percentage of jobs, etc. All the details are in the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel.html.

Comment: Re: "I don't think there's an easy solution with a for loop and wait": indded, attempt to use `wait_pid $pid &` leads to `t5.sh: line 125: wait: pid 10921 is not a child of this shell`.

Comment: GNU parallel 20161222 says: `parallel: Error: --halt now must be followed by ,success or ,fail.`.

Comment: Do I need to export _all_ nested functions and variables? Otherwise, it says `environment: foo: command not found`. Does `set -o allexport` need to be used?

Comment: @pmor If it's simpler maybe you can put the job in a separate shell script? That way, it's a separate command altogether and you don't need to export functions.

Comment: @pmor Another solution is "set -o allexport" (or "set -a" which does the same). Remember to do it _before_ the functions and variables you wish to export.

Comment: FYI: Re: `export -f do_job`:  "[Array variables may not (yet) be exported.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564589/1778275)"

Comment: @pmor Hmm that's the issue with "allexport" I guess. It's probably simpler to just put the individual job in a separate script and pass it argument on the command line.

Comment: Re: "put the individual job in a separate script": OK. However, for the moment I've rolled back to using subshells (via `&`) followed by checking their status (running / not running) using 0.5s polling (yes, polling is considered suboptimal). If subshell X failed (exit status != 0), then kill (using `SIGTERM`) all descendant subshells recursively AND return 1 (to trigger the same "If subshell X failed..." logic at the upper level in tree). This logic is somehow similar to `--halt now,fail=1` ("[exit when a job has failed. Kill running jobs](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)").